# PyMongo - Querying list of embedded documents

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

There are a few posts here about this but not exactly what I'm after.

I have a document that contains a list of embedded documents:

```
{
   "_id": 1234
   "name": "joe"
   "comments": [
       {"type": "text", "content": "my content"},
       {"type": "image", "content": "my_content"}
       {"type": "image", "content": "my_content"}
   ]

}
```

I want to run one query that gets a set of documents then I was hoping to run a secondary query to search the "comments" list from that initial query set.

e.g `p = db.people.find({"some":"condition"})` and then search the embedded docs like `p.find({"type":"image"}`

This obviously doesn't work. Just wondering if there's a way to do this without having to run 2 separate queries over the parent document collection again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to just find the items in a collection that satisfy a given condition and *also* satisfy `{"type": "image"}` in the `comments` array, you can do that in a single query:

```
p = db.people.find({"some": "condition", "comments.type": "image"})
```

See the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) page for more info.

If you do actually need the whole thing, and you're interested in specific sub-items from said result, then the best method that I can think of is just to slurp in the result into a list, and check it in Python. Do any PyMongo gurus have anything to say on this? Note that, if your dataset is large, then this is **not** a good idea.

```
p = list(db.people.find({"some": "condition"})

# A little verbose, but...
image_p = [item for item in p
           if any(comment['type'] == 'image'
                  for comment in item['comments'])]

...
```

Comment: thanks. Sorry I should've mentioned that I need to run several secondary queries on the list like "comments.type": "image" and then "comments.type": "something else" etc. so a single query wouldn't work.

Comment: @GivP: I made a quick edit with one idea, although it may not be the best.

Comment: Yes I think this is probably the best approach. It's how I ended up doing it also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem using only `find` with the dot notation is that **you'll always get the whole document** and **not only the sub document.**

use mongodb 2.2 to be able to use [Aggregation](http://blog.pythonisito.com/2012/06/using-mongodbs-new-aggregation.html).

[look here](https://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/9cfb62609de046ee/d6ff897143c1a158?hl=fr&)

nb: [$ElementMatch](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24elemMatch) does not iteration when it is used with positional element (`something.$.someattribute`), it will exit just after the first document matched, so use aggregation to get all the sub documents that matches :)